# Como restringir la busqueda de google maps autocomplete a una zona en especifico

Tags: javascript, google-maps

tengo una duda, quiero que al escribir en el input del autocomplete solo salgan resultados relacionados con cierta zona, en mi caso es "Concepcion" (chile) que corresponde a administrative_area_level_3, lei en un post de alguien que queria hacer algo parecido pero en una app de android y le respondieron que es posible añadiendo la opcion de "components" en la url del script donde se llama a la api, intente hacer lo mismo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?components=administrative_area:concepción&key=KEY&libraries=places,geometry">
</script>
```

Pero no logro hacer que funcione, en que esta fallando?.
Aqui esta la documentacion de google donde habla de esto: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#component-filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferencia de la geocodificación, en donde se puede restringir el resultado a niveles administrativos (usando `components`), en [autompletar](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-multiple-countries), **hasta el momento** solo se puede restringir por paises y/o por "coordenadas limites" (bounds), no por `administrative_area` o `postal_code`. Otra diferencia es que se le pasan las opciones al constructor, ejemplo:

```
const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
  const options = {
    bounds: defaultBounds,
    componentRestrictions: { country: "cl" }, //<-- cl es el ISO de Chile
    fields: ["address_components", "geometry", "icon", "name"],
    origin: center,
    strictBounds: false,
    types: ["establishment"],
  };

  const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```